# Update between excel & Microsoft Visio

Tags: excel, visio

I had create an Organization chart browse from the excel. My problem is: How can I update my Microsoft Visio Organization chart when I insert a new data record into the excel.

I had the "Link Data Shape" between my excel file and visio organization chart. But when I insert a new record into the excel, I found that my visio could not update and change the chart itself when I refresh the "Data Shape" in visio.

Is there any way to do it or I can only recreate the organization chart again?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no automatic addition, deletion or movement of people with the Org Chart Add-in. You could automate an Org Chart better without using this add-in. See http://blog.bvisual.net/2009/02/24/creating-an-org-chart-without-the-org-chart-wizard/ for more information.